# Rails 5: insert name in form and save id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 4 tables:users, observative_session, observations, celestial_bodies.
Each user has many observative_session and each observative_session has many observations. I already put in the model the associations
So in observative_session I have a foreign_key (user_id) to link it to the user and in observation I have one foreign key (user_id) for the user and a foreign key (observative_session_id) for the observative_session plus another foreign key for the celestial_body (celestial_body_id).
I created a form in which I ask the user to insert the name of a celestial body

```
<%= f.text_field :celestial_body_id, label: 'Celestial body' %>
```

but I can't save the string as an id so I need to find the id corresponding to the inserted body and save it instead.
I tryed to define a virtual attribute

```
def celestial_body_name
  CelestialBody.where(' ')
end
def celestial_body_name= (name)
  celestyal_body_id = CelestialBody.where(name: celestial_body_name)
end
```

and then I create the new observation

```
def create
@observation = @observative_session.observations.build(observation_params)
....
end
```

but I get the undefined method 'observations' for nil:NilClass
I don't understand if I pass the parameters correctly or not.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You probably want a `select` instead of a text field to associate a "Celestial body". Something like `f.select :celestial_body_id, options_for_select(CelestialBody.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] })`

Comment: You get the `undefined method 'observations' for nil:NilClass` error because `@observative_session` is `nil`

Comment: I know it's nil, but I don't know why since if I make the form write the id of @observative_session it writes it correctily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with some autocomplete solution as https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete. You need to think about passing additional hidden field as celestial_body_id to create valid association in controller. I think this part should help you -- https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete#sending-extra-search-fields.

Of course you can still pass name without autocomplete, but it's bad for UI (you never know whether such category exists and you can even make some typo in it) and it will require additional queries on logic on backend side

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use select because there are too many celestial body to show

Comment: Updated my answer